# Slk 200: Remove A-pillar to hide microphone

Tags: mercedes-benz, dashboard, slk230

I bought a new car radio with a cable connected microphone. Now I need to hide the cable in the A-pillar and then connect it to the behind of the radio.

Does anyone know how to remove the A-pillar and also the dashboard in a Mercedes SLK 200? (R171)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't advise you on how to remove the dashboard since it tends to be dependant on the car and I'm not 100% familiar with your car, but the A-pillar trims are clipped in and will pop off with a bit of force. Get a flathead screw driver in the seam and pop it out, there will be a few clips so you'll have to pop it off of.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to fit the microphone in the roof light and you don’t make this clear then there may be another method.

I used a “pull cord”, actually a truck speedo cable as it is long.

It is possible, on some cars, to feed the pull cord from the centre lamp; across the roof; and down the A pillar to be found under the dash.

This takes patience and some skill (gained by fitting many roof aerials...), also a small (10 degree) bend on the last inch of the pull cord can help turn corners...